# What should I do after I write webdriver tests? how do I run them automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, functional-testing

I'm testing this website:

[image: website]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    WebDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver();

    
    firefox.get("http://test.naimi.me");
    
    WebElement row = firefox.findElement(By.className("row"));
    
    
   
    WebElement navigationPane = 
            firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[contains(@nav,'nav')]"));
    
    
    WebElement billboard = firefox.findElement(By.id("billboard")) ;
    if(billboard != null) System.out.println("good bilboard") ;
```

I have some Java test code to check if elements loaded after opening the main page. How do I make it run automatically? and on what server/software? Maybe cloud?

Comment: There's a lot of... things here, notwithstanding the fact that the "cloud" isn't the end-all thing that you need to hook into somehow.  "Running automatically" is also very subjective and depends on what continuous integration server you're using.  If you've not heard of a CI service like Jenkins or CircleCI, I would suggest that you start there (at least, as far as automatically running the tests).  I'll say that the test itself needs some work (i.e. assert statements), but I've got a feeling that you're just getting started with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my way: TestNG + Selenium-Grid + Jenkins CI.

[TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) is a test framework which is designed to cover all categories of tests:  unit, functional, end-to-end, integration, etc...

[Selenium-Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) allows you to :

- scale by distributing tests on several machines ( parallel execution )
- manage multiple environments from a central point, making it easy to run the tests against a vast combination of browsers / OS.
- minimize the maintenance time for the grid by allowing you to implement custom hooks to leverage virtual infrastructure for instance.

[Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is the leading open-source continuous integration server, which could be used to run your tests  automatically and continuously.

Comment: i actually was following same path, installed testng already... thx! i will add to this toolchain grid and jenkins.

Comment: also you could use onlineservices like browserstack.com or saucelabs.com to run your tests in different configured virtual machines.